# Find text based on common ID

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find text based on a common phrase.  The thing is, the text that I will need to copy out is below the text that I will be searching.  For example:

> 7.  Amazon emailed seller
>
> Friday, February 2, 2018

"Amazon emailed seller" will be consistent, but I need the date that is below it.

Another example:

> Claim Amount:
>
> 14.97

"Claim Amount:" will be consistent, but I need the amount that is below it.

In the end I am wanting to create a macro (or VBA function if macro is not possible, I apologize for not knowing) that will allow me to search on "Claim Amount:"/"Amazon emailed seller" or another common phrase and will then move the contents of the cell below them to another cell in another workbook.  I will not have a cell location for the search to reference because the information I am exporting pastes differently into Excel each time.

Please let me know if you have any questions or if I should clarify anything.  I am new to this website and not exactly sure how to phrase my question to be as clear as possible.  My apologies in advance.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use INDEX/MATCH combo. https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but you haven't actually asked a question. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do - when you say "'Claim Amount:' will be consistent, but I need the amount that is below it.", do you mean that the amount is in the cell directly below the text "Claim Amount:"? So all you need is a formula to point to the cell below that text?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion.  Yes, I mean that I need the text directly below "Claim Amount:".  For example, "Claim Amount:" is in cell A1, but "14.97" is in cell A2.  Hope that helps, thanks for asking.

Comment: Thanks Tom!  I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fast approach using a

- A) **datafield array** instead of a `Range` *(base data assumed in column A)*.
- B) All found results are **written back** to a pair of columns that you can change to any other range or a new workbook.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub extract()
' declare and assign variables
  Dim header()
      header = Array("Amazon emailed seller", "Claim Amount") ' headers
  Dim ws As Worksheet                                   ' sheet object (objects have to be SET)
  Dim v                                                 ' variant datafield array
  Dim i  As Long, ii As Long, h As Long, n  As Long     ' counters
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")           ' << change to your sheet name
  n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row       ' get last row in column A
' A) create datafield array and  loop through items
  v = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:B" & n).Value) ' fill 1-based 2-dim datafield array (TWO Columns!)
  For i = 1 To n                                          ' loop through array "row"-items
    For h = LBound(header) To UBound(header)            ' loop through header items
      If InStr(v(1, i), header(h)) Then                 ' check search string against base text
         ii = ii + 1                                    ' increment array counter
         v(1, ii) = v(1, i):  v(2, ii) = v(1, i + 1)    ' enter found values (both rows)
      End If
    Next h
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve v(1 To 2, 1 To ii)                     ' redimension array to actual items count
' -------------------------------------------
' B) Write back results (e.g. in columns D:E)           ' << change to ANY wanted pair of columns
' -------------------------------------------
  ws.Range("D:E") = ""                                  '    clear columns D:E to get result
  ws.Range("D1:E" & ii) = Application.Transpose(v)      '    write summary back to columns D:E
' C) Clear memory
  Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you know that the text you are looking for will appear somewhere in A1:A20.

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH("Claim Amount:",A1:A20,0)+1)
```

If you do not know which column the text will appear in, you will need to do a match for each possible column OR change your approach (perhaps a helper column).

Answer (score 0):

you could filter all the database in one shot on wanted headers and then get the cells on row below filtered ones

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dataToKeep As Range
    Dim headers As Variant

    headers = Array("*Amazon emailed seller", "Claim Amount*") 'list your headers (see asterisks for wild characters)

    With Worksheets("mySheetName") ' change "mySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'reference its column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=headers, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter reference cells on wnated headers
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 0 Then Set dataToKeep = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1) ' if any filtered cell then get their underlying cells
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    If Not dataToKeep Is Nothing Then
        ' code to handle all data underlying the searched "header" cells
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Heather, any feedback?